# Want to center navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Here is my code, I have tried many things, help me Obiwan! I tried to do a container tag, ro response to css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- This sets up bootstrap 3-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="veiwport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1">
  <!-- this sets initial zoom when page is loaded -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- links css -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lauren Neely</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sketchbook + Misc</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
   .navbar-nav{
     text-align:center;
     float:none;
   }
   .navbar-nav li{
     float:none;
     display:inline-block;
   }
}
```

with `float: none` you set central align to your `.navbar-nav`

and setting `@media (min-width: 768px)` you can apply these rules only for desktop and tablet views. For mobile bootstrap handle navbar in responsive way, so is not necessary.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- This sets up bootstrap 3-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1">
  <!-- this sets initial zoom when page is loaded -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- links css -->
<style>
@media (min-width: 768px)
    .navbar-nav{
      text-align:center;
      float:none;
    }
   .navbar-nav li{
      float:none;
      display:inline-block;
    }
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lauren Neely</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Sketchbook + Misc</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```